# Passing .csv File From One Button To Another To Upload It Into Database

Tags: c#, mysql

This is my first time using a form so I'm a bit new to this.

I'm working on a form that allows users to pick a .csv file from their local disk and upload/ insert it into the database to update a table.

My form looks like this:

[image]

With the `select file` button, a user can pick a .csv file and the path of that file will be displayed in the textbox above the button. If a user clicks on the `Upload File` button, it uploads the selected .csv file into the database.

**What I Have Achieved So Far:**

Now, I successfully managed to make the part where a user can pick a .csv file, and the path of the file will be displayed in the textbox.

but I can't seem to get the second button to work.

**My Question:**

- How do I take the file from the first button and use it in the second
  button to update it into a database?

**My Code:**

My code for the buttons is as follows:

```
    public System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    public System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;

    public void Button()
    {
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
    }

    public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse .csv Files";

        openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
        openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;

        openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".csv";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Csv files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;



        openFileDialog1.ReadOnlyChecked = true;

        openFileDialog1.ShowReadOnly = true;



        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            Button2();
        }
    }

    public void Button2()
    {
        button2.Click += new EventHandler(Button2_Click);
    }

    public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Console.WriteLine("[Core] Opening database connection.");
            if (Database.stockConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Database.openStockConn(Settings.databaseName, Settings.databaseUsername, Settings.databasePassword, Settings.sshHost, Settings.sshUsername, Settings.sshPassword);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("[Core] database connection is now open!\n");

            Database.stockConn.Open();
            try
                    {
   // not sure if 'textBox1.Text' is the right variable for the file
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("LOAD DATA INFILE" + textBox1.Text + "INTO TABLE catalog_product_entity_decimal_copy FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','");
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        MessageBox.Show("File Has Been Uploaded Into The Database SuccessFully!");
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Couldn't Upload File Into Database!");
                    }
        }
```

In the code above I've used `textBox1.Text` as variable for the selected .csv file but I don't think that this is the variable I should use to make this work.

So if anybody could help me/explain to me how I can pass the .csv file from the first button to the second button, it would be very appriciated.

**EDIT:**

As requested by some people here is an edit:

My problem is not that my Query isn't working, yes the Query that I've given as example isn't completely correct but its just as an example. I know how to write/execute a proper Query in C# / MySql.

And:

In my example I've used `textBox1.Text` as my file but this doesn't work because `textBox1.Text` is just the path from the file and not the file.

Comment: Why do you think `testBox1.Text` is the wrong variable? Also, parameterize your queries.

Comment: Your textbox will hold the file path. Then you have to read the data in using `System.IO`.

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain what this code does or doesn't do. If you catch all exceptions and simply display a messagebox, you won't know what went wrong.

Comment: This has already been touched on to some extent, but what happens if `textbox1.Text` happens to have a double quote in it somewhere?

Comment: @CodeCaster how is my question a duplicate of that question?? My question is about how I can pass a csv file from one button to another so when I click the second button, it uploads that file into an database. that guy's question is not even about an c# form! my problem isn't the query, yes it isn't correct in the example i've given but that's not what my question is about. I know how to run a proper query in c# / mysql! so please reopen my question, thanks.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb because `testBox1.Text` is just the path from the file and yeah the query in the example I've given isn't completely correct, but its just an example. Trust me it's not going to look like that when its finished.

Comment: You haven't edited, so I'm not gonna reopen. Read [ask] and ask an answerable question. You're not _"passing a file from a button to a button"_, that makes no sense, you're trying to use a string from a textbox in a SQL query. Reading the text from a textbox is as simple as getting its `Text` property. If that doesn't do what you expect it to, then **explain what you expect and what actually happens**. If this code indeed doesn't work, it's because you lack spaces and quotes in your SQL command, as explained in the duplicate. The forms part is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @CodeCaster I made an edit, if it still doesn't fit your satisfaction than not. have a good day.

Comment: _"this doesn't work because textBox1.Text is just the path from the file and not the file"_ - that's exactly how LOAD DATA INFILE is supposed to work. You pass a path, not the file's contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like the below.

Declare your file dialog privately or drag a file dialog control onto your form in design mode which would achieve the same. Once done, you can then reference the dialogs FileName property and assign to a textbox or just use the property directly from the control.

```
private readonly FileDialog _fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

private void btnSelectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        txtPathToFile.Text = _fileDialog.FileName;
    }
}
```

If declared within an event, then assign the FileName property to a textbox.

```
var myFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

if (myFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     txtPathToFile.Text = myFileDialog.FileName;
}
```

To get the path. Again either access the dialog controls FileName property or you can assign it to a text box and read its text value. Either way is fine.

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pathFromDialogControl = _fileDialog.FileName;
    var pathFromTextBox = txtPathToFile.Text;
    //Do something here
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering! will definitely look into this!